# Getting an unusual output for a simple constructor program in C++

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I am a novice at C++ and have encountered an unusual error while trying to learn about constructors. Here I am trying to make x = 5 and y = 6, then have the program print them out to the screen.

This is my program ->

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class class1 {
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
        class1(int x, int y) {
            x = x;
            y = y;
        }
}




int main() {
class1 class1obj(5, 6);
cout << class1obj.x << endl << class1obj.y;

}
```

This is my output after 3 runs ->

1st run

```
172691493
1
```

2nd run

```
126890021
1
```

3rd run

```
226783269
1
```

As you can see from the outputs, y seems to be a constant '1' whereas x just seems to change continuously through random numbers.
This program is fairly simple so I have not a clue on what is going wrong here.

It should also be noted that I am on a mac OS big sur and I use g++ -std=c++11 as my compiler as g++ does not seem to work for all my programs (and yes I have tried g++ on its own for this specific program and it still does not work).

Any help will be much Appreciated!

Comment: Remove the constructor completely (you would be using aggregate initialization in this case) or rename whether the parameters of your constructor or your members. You are just modifying the parameters and leaving your members uninitialized.

Comment: Think about the `x = x` assignment in the constructor. In the scope of the constructor function what is the variable `x`? It can only be *one* thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This :

```
   class1(int x, int y) {
        x = x;
        y = y;
    }
```

is called shadowing. A variable shadows another one of same name. `x = x` just assigns the value of the parameter `x` to itself and the members are left uninitialized. The compiler has no way to know that you want one `x` to be the member and the other be the parameter, instead the parameter is said to "shadow" the member and in `x = x;` the `x` is the parameter. You should use different names:

```
   class1(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
```

or use the member initializer list (which you should prefer anyhow):

```
   class1(int a, int b) : x(a),y(b) {}
```

There is no ambiguity in the initializer list about what `x` refers to:

```
   class1(int x, int y) : x(x),y(y) {}
```

In `x(x)` the first `x` can only refer to the member and the second `x` can only refer to the argument.

Comment: *"in the initializer list, there is no shadowing"*. There is, but only at *"expected"* places.

Comment: @Jarod42 sometimes less is more ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That solves my problem, thank you, but why were the numbers so random in my code before.

Comment: @HYP3R_F0CUS because reading from uninitialized variables is undefined behavior. The output of your code could be anything. Btw be careful with "random". Random values have certain properties, they are drawn from some random distribution. Your output was unexpected, wrong, but not "random" according to any meaningful definition of randomness